# how to create ordered data in XML

Tags: xml

I want to define a polygon as a sequence of points like so:

```
<polygon>
   <point x="0"     y="0" z="0" />
   <point x="100.0" y="100.0" z="100.0" />
   <point x="50.0"  y="100.0" z="50.0"  />
</polygon>
```

It is important that the order of points is preserved when I read them in

I've written the following xsd file:

```
<xs:element  name="point_type">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs::double"/>
      <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs::double"/>
      <xs:attribute name="z" type="xs::double"/>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="polygon_type">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="point" type="point_type"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

but sombody noted that `xs:sequence` does not necessarily mean that the `<points>` will be in order. 
Indeed, http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp seems to define that sequence

```
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="A" type="A_type"/>
      <xs:element name="B" type="B_type"/>
    </xs:sequence>
```

would only make sure that `B`'s are after `A`'s

```
<super>
  <A/>
  <B/>
  <A/>
  <B/>
</super>
```

and does not say anything about the order of the {A-B} pairs.

Does anybody know about this? 
Can you point me to references that support one argument or the other?

Comment: Suggest changing name to "how to create ordered data in XML" or such.  Did not edit myself since I considered this too substantial without OP consent.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add an `id` attribute to the points so that you can explicitly track the order of the points in your application rather than relying on the XML parser to return the elements in the right order. All XML parsers I have used, do obey element ordering but I could not find anything in the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) about this.

```
<polygon>
   <point id="0" x="0"     y="0" z="0" />
   <point id="1" x="100.0" y="100.0" z="100.0" />
   <point id="2" x="50.0"  y="100.0" z="50.0"  />
</polygon>
```

Comment: is there a trick I could use on the definition side instead (in the schema) so that I can do without having to add the ordering attribute `id`? It's really important that I have to save as much disk space as possible